# GLSL shader error: cannot convert from '2-component vector of int' to '2-component vector of float'

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, shader

I write a frag shader on Android NDK, but it gives me an compile error:

```
AdrenoGLES-0: ERROR: 0:11: 'assign' :  cannot convert from '2-component vector of int' to '2-component vector of float'
AdrenoGLES-0: ERROR: 1 compilation errors.  No code generated.
AdrenoGLES-0:
shader_tag     : testTextureChangeFs : ERROR: 0:11: 'assign' :  cannot convert from '2-component vector of int' to '2-component vector of float'
shader_tag     : ERROR: 1 compilation errors.  No code generated.
```

I don't known what's worry with it, Here is my vert/frag shader code:

The vert shader code:

```
#version 300 es
in vec4 position;
in vec2 texcoord0;
layout(location = 0) uniform mat4 mvp;
layout(location = 1) uniform int flip_y;
out vec2 vTexcoord0;
void main() {
    gl_Position = mvp * position;
    gl_Position.y = -gl_Position.y;
    vTexcoord0 = texcoord0;
    if (flip_y == 1) {
        vTexcoord0.y = 1.0 - vTexcoord0.y;
    }
}
```

The frag shader code:

```
#version 300 es
precision highp float;
uniform sampler2D srcTex;
in vec2 vTexcoord0;
layout(location = 2) uniform vec2 offset;
layout(location = 3) uniform vec2 extent;
out vec4 outColor;
void main ()
{
    vec2 uv_sub = offset + vTexcoord0 * extent;
    uv_sub /= textureSize(srcTex, 0);
    outColor = texture(srcTex, uv_sub); // compile failed !!!
}
```

Comment: Are you really sure the line with the comment is the problem and not the one above it? My guess would be that it complains about dividing a vec2 by an ivec2 (the result of textureSize).

Comment: ... `uv_sub /= vec2(textureSize(srcTex, 0));`